# Migrating to GitHub Actions from Travis keeps failing

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, building-github-actions

I am currently completing a migration from travis CI to Github Actions CI however my build keeps failing when the container tries to connect to my test DB.

Its a very generic error

UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: An internal error has occurred. Please retry or report your issues.

```
  at Handshake.Object.<anonymous>.Sequence._packetToError (node_modules/***/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
  at Handshake.Object.<anonymous>.Handshake.ErrorPacket (node_modules/***/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
  at Protocol.Object.<anonymous>.Protocol._parsePacket (node_modules/***/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
  at Parser._parsePacket (node_modules/***/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
  at Parser.write (node_modules/***/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
  at Protocol.Object.<anonymous>.Protocol.write (node_modules/***/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules/***/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules/***/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
```

Additional Notes: My test DB is hosted on Azure (mysql server) and my tests execute fine on local and previously on travis. Project details: NodeJs project running TypeOrm for MySql.

This is what the current base version of my yml looks like:

````
on: 
  pull_request:
    branches: [master, develop]
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./Server
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js
        with: 
            node_version: 14.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      - name: Run tests
        run: |                                           
          npm install
          npx jest --coverage --config ./jest.config.js 
        env:
          TEST_DB_NAME: ${{ secrets.TEST_DB_NAME }}
          TEST_DB_PORT: ${{ secrets.TEST_DB_PORT }}
          TEST_DB_TYPE: ${{ secrets.TEST_DB_TYPE }}
          TEST_HOST: ${{ secrets.TEST_HOST }}                              
          TEST_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.TEST_PASSWORD }}
          TEST_PORT: ${{ secrets.TEST_PORT }}
          ACCESS_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_SECRET_KEY }} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

I was missing an extra env key/variable related to an external AP. This was causing the failure.